# get the differences in value of documents between two indexes in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a use case where in, I have two indexes in elasticsearch `index_old`, `index_new` which will have

- almost similar number records
- almost similar documents values
- both indexes have a field name `unique_id`, value for which, is same and acts as primary key

sample records for `index_old`

```
{
  "unique_id": "french_toast",
  "name": "French Toast",
  "description": "French toast is a dish made of sliced bread soaked in beaten eggs, sugar and typically milk, then pan fried",
  "ingredients": ["bread", "eggs", "sugar", "oil", "milk"]
}

{
  "unique_id": "japanese_cheesecake",
  "name": "Japanese cheesecake",
  "description": "Japanese cheesecake is a variety of cheesecake that is usually lighter in texture and less sweet than North American-style cheesecakes",
  "ingredients": ["cream Cheese", "butter", "sugar", "egg"]
}

{
  "unique_id": "kimchi",
  "name": "Kimchi",
  "description": "Kimchi, is a traditional Korean side dish of salted and fermented vegetables, such as napa cabbage and Korean radish",
  "ingredients": ["fermented cabbage", "radish", "cucumber"]
}

{
  "unique_id": "turkish_delight",
  "name": "turkish delight",
  "description": "Turkish delight or lokum is a family of confections based on a gel of starch and sugar",
  "ingredients": ["starch", "sugar"]
}
```

sample records for `index_new`

```
{
  "unique_id": "french_toast",
  "name": "French Toast",
  "description": "French toast is a dish made of sliced bread soaked in beaten eggs, sugar and typically milk, then pan fried",
  "ingredients": ["bread", "eggs", "sugar", "oil", "milk"]
}

{
  "unique_id": "japanese_cheesecake",
  "name": "Japanese cheesecake",
  "description": "Japanese cheesecake also known as soufflé-style cheesecake, cotton cheesecake, or light cheesecake is a variety of cheesecake that is usually lighter in texture and less sweet than North American-style cheesecakes",
  "ingredients": ["cream Cheese", "butter", "sugar", "egg", "butter"]
}

{
  "unique_id": "kimchi",
  "name": "Kimchi",
  "description": "Kimchi, is a traditional Korean side dish of salted and fermented vegetables, such as napa cabbage and Korean radish",
  "ingredients": ["fermented cabbage", "radish", "cucumber", "soya sauce", "ginger", "garlic"]
}

{
  "unique_id": "turkish_delight",
  "name": "turkish delight",
  "description": "Turkish delight or lokum is a family of confections based on a gel of starch and sugar",
  "ingredients": ["starch", "sugar", "pistachios", "dry fruits"],
  "origin": "turkey"
}
```

Only unique_id `french_toast` is same, difference in values of other documents between index_old and index_new are

1. unique_id: `japanese_cheesecake` =>

   - `description` is changed
   - `ingredients` is changed
2. unique_id: `kimchi` =>

   - `ingredients` is changed
3. unique_id: `turkish_delight` =>

   - `ingredients` is changed
   - new field `origin` is added.

Only way I can think of, is using python script( as I mostly work on python ), query and compare the document values of both the indexes using brute force approach, which includes querying multiple times in elastic search, which I think is not so good way to go.

Is there a way, by which I can get the above differences between the documents of two indexes, either by one or more queries in elasticsearch entirely?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi I am not sure there is a good solution to your issue. Sadly I think you need to resort to the python script I am user as to how to perform it inside elasticsearch

Comment: Your approach would work, I believe. Also, It is not directly possible in Elastic Search.

Answer (score 0):

there's nothing that can do this natively in Elasticsearch unfortunately. your best bet is to handle it externally in your own code